# Twilio - IfMachine rest code

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

Is there a way to find whether the voice call is answered by machine or human . We came to know from the REST docs that if machine will be deprecated . If that so , whether the below code will work

```
*Call call = Call
            .creator(new PhoneNumber(phSettings.getQueueConnectNumber()), new PhoneNumber(callnum),
                new URI(url))

            .setIfMachine("Hangup")
            .setMethod(HttpMethod.GET).setStatusCallback(statusurl)
            .setStatusCallbackMethod(HttpMethod.POST).setStatusCallbackEvent(callbackEvents).create(RestClient);*
```

Also from the docs we found MachineDetection is in beta , will we be get beta access for our testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering Machine Detection is in public beta so you can start experimenting with it right away.

The `IfMachine` parameter will be deprecated so you will need to update your code. For example, use the `MachineDetection` parameter as `Enable` or `DetectMessageEnd`. `Enable` returns results as soon as recognition is complete. `DetectMessageEnd` will wait until after a greeting to return results if an answering machine is detected.

As call to the API as seen in [the docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/answering-machine-detection):

```
curl 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX123456789/Calls.json' -X POST \
--data-urlencode 'To=+1562300000' \
--data-urlencode 'From=+18180000000' \
--data-urlencode 'MachineDetection=Enable' \
--data-urlencode 'Url=https://handler.twilio.com/twiml/EH8ccdbd7f0b8fe34357da8ce87ebe5a16' \
-u ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX123456789:[AuthToken]
```

Comment: Thanks for responding but we dont find this machine detection in our latest 
com.twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.call java API . 
Can you help in locating this class or example code in java?

Comment: The [latest version of the Java SDK has support for the `MachineDetection` parameter](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-java/blob/985a78929c8c7881fb8dfa124236e3a102413767/src/main/java/com/twilio/rest/api/v2010/account/CallCreator.java#L46). Make sure you have the latest version installed. :)